# How to convert string to array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following string:

```
"[['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]"
```

and I want to convert it to array of object

```
[['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]
```

I've tried to do many things but I could not

```
        function nextQuess() {
        var ffa = JSON.stringify("<%- hola %>");  // from ejs variable "[['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]"
        // var ff = JSON.parse([ffa])
        // console.log('hello', ff);
        console.log("Hello", ffa);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace `'` by `"` and then parse

```
 '(.*?)'(?=(,|\])
```

- `'(.*?)'` - Match ' followed by anything zero more time ( Lazy mode ) ( Capture group 1)
- `(?=(,|\]))` - Match must be followed by `,` or `]`

```js
let str = "[['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]"

let replacedString = str.replace(/'(.*?)'(?=(,|\]))/g, "\"$1\"")
let final = JSON.parse(replacedString)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I receive this error ```VM3089:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ```

Comment: @RafaelPereira where you're trying to run this code. i tried in codepen, console and vscode, i don't see this error occurring, BTW you can drop that part where i replaced `"` by `\`` see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(json)` and then `JSON.parse()`

```js
let jsonString = JSON.stringify([['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]);
let array = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(array);
```

Or you can also try [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method

```js
let jsonArray = eval([['ABB','ACC','ADD'],['FGG','FHH','FJJJ'],['MNN','MOO','MPP']]);
console.log(jsonArray);
```